# Pickling issue with python pathos

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

```
import pathos.multiprocessing as mp
class Model_Output_File():
    """
    Class to read Model Output files
    """
    def __init__(self, ftype = ''):
        """
        Constructor
        """
        # Create a sqlite database in the analysis directory
        self.db_name = 'sqlite:///' + constants.anly_dir + os.sep + ftype + '_' + '.db'
        self.engine  = create_engine(self.db_name)
        self.ftype   = ftype

    def parse_DGN(self, fl):
        df      = pandas.read_csv(...)
        df.to_sql(self.db_name, self.engine, if_exists='append')

    def collect_epic_output(self, fls):
        pool = mp.ProcessingPool(4)
        if(self.ftype == 'DGN'):
            pool.map(self.parse_DGN, fls)
        else:
            logging.info( 'Wrong file type')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_fls = fnmatch.filter(...)
    obj = Model_Output_File(ftype = 'DGN')
    obj.collect_model_output(list_fls)
```

In the code above, I am using the pathos multiprocessing library to avoid python multiprocessing issues with classes. However I am getting a pickling error:

```
  pool.map(self.parse_DGN, fls)
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\site-packages\pathos-0.2a1.dev0-py2.7.egg\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 131, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Anaconda64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  You are getting a `cPickle.PicklingError`… which you should not get with `pathos`.  Do you have `multiprocess` installed, and if you do, do you have a C compiler?  You can check for pickling errors by importing `dill`, and doing a `dill.copy` on the object.  If that works, then you probably have some installation issue, where `pathos` is finding the standard library version of `multiprocessing` and not the fork that provides better serialization.

Comment: thanks @MikeMcKerns, I do have multiprocessing installed. What exactly do I do dill.copy on?

Comment: From the error message, I seem to be ending up in "C:\Anaconda64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", which seems to indicate what you are saying about pathos finding the standard library version of multiprocessing.

Comment: You'd `dill.copy(self.parse_DGN)`.  So if you are finding the python standard library `multiprocessing`, then you probably need to install a compiler… like Microsoft Visual Studio Community.  See: https://github.com/mmckerns/tuthpc

Comment: hmm, dill.copy(...) works, and error is still persisting after install NS Visual Studio Express...

Comment: did you then rebuild `multiprocess` after the install of the MS compiler?

Comment: ah, I did not. ok will try that

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, I did a pip uninstall multiprocess and then a pip install multiprocess, that does not seem to help. Maybe I should build from source. However, I just cannot seem to find multiprocess code. Do you know where it is?

Comment: ok did pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/multiprocess.git. still getting same issue :(

Comment: Ok, that seems odd.  `multiprocess` should just `pip install` with no problems.  Maybe you can post this as a ticket on the `multiprocess` github page?  That way, I can better diagnose your traceback?  The only other thing I can think of w/o seeing tracebacks / build output is that you have an unusual PYTHONPATH.

Comment: thank you so much @MikeMcKerns, turns out I was wrong re the C compiler. Just tried building multiprocess from source code (setup.py build), turns out it complains about a C compiler not being installed. I did install visual studio community yesterday so maybe it is a case of some path being wrong as you said

Comment: Cool. Enjoy!  If you find you have further issues, feel free to submit a ticket.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns, if you can write your comment as an answer, i will be happy to accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `pathos` author. You are getting a `cPickle.PicklingError`… which you should not get with `pathos`.  Make sure you have `multiprocess` installed, and if you do, that you have a C++ compiler. You can check for pickling errors by importing `dill`, and doing a `dill.copy(self.parse_DGN)` inside your class, or externally using the instance of the class. If that works, then you probably have some installation issue, where `pathos` is finding the python standard library `multiprocessing`.  If so, then you probably need to install a compiler… like Microsoft Visual Studio Community. See: [github.com/mmckerns/tuthpc](http://github.com/mmckerns/tuthpc).  Make sure to rebuild `multiprocess` after the install of the MS compiler.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. Mystery is that the same identical code works on 1 win7 machine and not another win7!
Then I checked the versions --- turned out dill and multiprocess were 1 version higher on the balky machine. I down-versioned dill and multiprocess to 0.2.5 and 0.70.4 respectively. And that solved the problem!
Hope that helps

Comment: this seems a bit odd.  When you down-versioned, did you also have an older version of python?  Because `multiprocess` is usually kept in step with the latest releases of `python`, as I essentially fork `multiprocessing` each new release.  If there's some incompatibility across minor versions of `python`, I'd be interested to hear about it.