# pathos multiprocessing cannot pickle

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pickle, pathos

I am having a similar issue to this [person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856206/pickling-issue-with-python-pathos#comment53610587_32856206). I am unable to run a simple multiprocessing routine in the pathos module and receive a pickling error.  Below is the code and error.

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
import dill
class ProcClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def f(self,x):
        return x*x
pc = ProcClass()
pl = ProcessingPool(3)
print pl.map(pc.f, range(10))
```

The returned error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 320, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

I have installed:  pp, dill, pox and multiprocessing then installed pathos. The install works but always gives me this error:

---

WARNING: One of the following dependencies is unresolved:
    pp(ft) >=1.6.4.5
    dill >=0.2.4
    pox >=0.2.2
    (multi)processing

---

Based on a response from the author of pathos to a similar question, it looks like there is a problem with the install. I have removed and reinstalled several times, each time verifying the proper dependancies are installed. I'm running on MacOS and using python 2.7.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm the author of the above packages. Can you give more detail how you installed, and which versions you installed?  I primarily use MacOS and python2.7, so it should be straightforward to test your install.

Comment: From your traceback, it looks like you are using the standard library versions of `multiprocessing`, `threading`, and `pickle`.  Essentially, not seeing any of the packages you say you installed.

Comment: I first downloaded the source [pathos-master] (https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos) and ran the python setup.py install and tried it but didn't work. Then I deleted multiprocessing (as well as pathos) from my site packages, installed the dependencies again for pathos and did a clean install of pathos.  Still didn't work.

Comment: If I try to run with regular multiprocessing I do get a slightly different error:  PicklingError: PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed rather than the previous:  Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed.  I don't know if this helps but there is a difference.

Comment: What I am asking is can you tell me how you installed all the dependencies and what are their versions?  For example, this *should* work: `>$ pip install setuptools` then `>$ pip install git+https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos.git@master`.  Then you can check the versions by importing and looking at `pathos.__version__`, for example.  You should also make sure you are installing to the same site-packages as the python you are using -- I know that's obvious, but I've seen folks do otherwise.

Comment: I verified that i am installing to the proper site-packages. I have the following versions installed there:  pathos version:   0.2a1.dev0
dill version:   0.2.5.dev0
pp version:   1.6.4.5
pox version:   0.2.2
multiprocessing version:   0.70a1.  In the pathos.multiprocessing.ProcessPool.map, self.serve returns a multiprocessing.pool.Pool object. I don't understand where dill is used instead of pickle. How/Where does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are missing a critical dependency.  With `pathos`, you should use `multiprocess`, which is a fork of `multiprocessing` which uses the `dill` serializer.

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.__version__
'0.70a1'
>>> import multiprocess   
>>> multiprocess.__version__
'0.70.4.dev0'
>>> 
>>> multiprocess.Pool().map(lambda x:x*x, range(10))
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike McKerns. This was a weird one. I tried to simply import multiprocess alone and could not because I received the following error from subprocess.py:  ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags.   It turns out that I was unable to import _args_from_interpreter_flags from the subprocess module. This is because it was simply not there. I don't know why it was not. The solution was to download python2.7 and simply copy and paste subprocess.py. The sample code above works now.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error. I changed my import part from:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
```

to:

```
import pathos, multiprocess
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
import dill
```

and the code works. Not sure what's happening though. Maybe like Mike mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856206/pickling-issue-with-python-pathos) that pathos is finding the system bundled `multiprocessing` package instead of `multiprocess`. And maybe explicitly importing it somehow fixed the issue...