# simple python program with multiprocessing pathos library

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pathos

Followup with this question [pathos multiprocessing cannot pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33008728/pathos-multiprocessing-cannot-pickle)

Running the code in one:

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1,2,3]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\\femto.niddk.nih.gov\C\All Projects\NMR High Pressure\Software\multiprocessing\multiprocessing_playground_2.py", line 12, in <module>
    results = ProcessingPool().map(b.boo, [[12,3,456],[8,9,10],['a','b','cde']])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pathos\multiprocessing.py", line 137, in map
    return _pool.map(star(f), zip(*args)) # chunksize
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
>>>
```

Here is some more imformation:

```
>>> pathos.__version__
'0.2.2.dev0'
>>> import multiprocess
>>> multiprocess.__version__
'0.70.5'
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.__version__
'0.70a1'
>>> multiprocess.Pool().map(lambda x:x*x, range(10))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
    multiprocess.Pool().map(lambda x:x*x, range(10))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\multiprocess\pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

What is going on? Why isn't working? Isn't Pathos library supposed to use dill instead of pickling?

Comment: A wild guess - can you import `dill`?

Comment: yes. >>> import dill>>> dill.__version__'0.2.7.1'. After searching online, I came to the conclusion that somehow pathos is still trying to use pickle instead. This was reported here https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/121 . The solution there doesn't work for me. There is another question similar to mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50747113/simple-python-program-with-multiprocessing-pathos-library?noredirect=1#comment88502552_50747113

Comment: I mistakenly put a wrong link address in the last line of previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250484/pathos-cpickle-error-on-python-2-7-13-14-using-windows-10?rq=1

Comment: it works  if i use 'from pathos.pools import ParallelPool as Pool' instead of 'from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it works if I use

```
from pathos.pools import ParallelPool as Pool
```

instead of

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool
```

of

```
from pathos.pools import ProcessPool as Pool
```

Who can explain what is the difference? All of these methods create different processes.