# Pathos Multiprocessing Pickling Issue

Tags: multiprocessing, pickle, dill, pathos

I am developing an automation framework for some testing we are doing on my team. We have come across this Pickling error and after doing some research, I came across a number of of solutions and reviewed the accompanying github page:

- [Python multiprocessing pickling error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804830/python-multiprocessing-pickling-error)
- [Multiprocessing: How to use Pool.map on a function defined in a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288595/multiprocessing-how-to-use-pool-map-on-a-function-defined-in-a-class)
- [Pickling issue with python pathos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856206/pickling-issue-with-python-pathos?newreg=11b52c7f24714b76b4fa3ad8462dc658) <---From this link, I confirmed the code is referencing the correct library.
- https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos

I installed pathos and believe I have implemented it correctly but I am still getting the Pickling error. Here is the  sample code and traceback:

```
import multiprocess

collect_host = 'test_host'
collect_name = 'test_collect'
username = 'user'

start_func = test_start_callback(perf_collect=collect_name,
                                 perf_user=username,
                                 perf_host=collect_host,
                                 password= password)

dpool = multiprocess.Pool(1)
args = ('', '')
worker_results = []
worker = dpool.apply_async(start_func, args)
worker_results.append(worker)
dpool.close()
dpool.join()

for result in worker_results:
        result.wait()
        r = result.get()
        assert r, 'No results returned'
```

The test_start_callback is a factory function to generate a function that takes no arguments. I edited out the code segment that isn’t used.

```
def test_start_callback(dim_collect_host=None, dim_collect_user=None, 
                        perf_host=None, perf_user=None, perf_collect=None, 
                        password=None, tpcc_filename=None):

    if perf_host and perf_user and perf_collect:
        def perf_test_start():
            from <internal> import PerfmonManager
            perf = PerfmonManager(host=perf_host,
                                  username=perf_user,
                                  password=password,
                                  collect_name=perf_collect)
            perf.start_collect()
    return perf_test_start
```

[Traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7mx8.png)

What am I missing that wasn't mentioned in the other SO links or is the way I'm passing this function not supported by pathos either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the `pathos` and `multiprocess` author.  This is a recent known issue that I'm not sure of the origin of yet... it's apparently surfaced in the past month without a change in the code.  I'm working actively to track down what the source of what the problem is.  It seems to only affect python `2.7`.

See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/pathos/issues/121

**UPDATE**: If this is the same issue as the above-referenced one, then all you need to do is clean out old builds (eggs, etc) of `multiprocess` and rebuild.  That seems to do it. For more information see the above URL.